# How to add photos/video to mysqldatabase without using blob?

Tags: php, database, netbeans, image-uploading

I am creating a form that lets users to upload their photos/ video and it will be saved into my database. May I know is there a way to get this done? Im trying to save it in the database using item_path varchar which means it looks. Example: img/cats.jpg . What can I do to make it to be added to the database? Thank you

Comment: save photo/video in a folder.

Comment: Store a link to the image/video in some column? The link could be to a public/private blob storage service like S3, Azure Storage or your custom in-house. That is how it should be generally done if your database is not specialized for blob storage. Saves you plenty!

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot create `BLOB` column types, then I would use a `TEXT` type with base64 encoding on the file data. You should take care to record the MIME type of the data and it would probably be a good idea to store a checksum (md5, or similar) as well.

Your `files` table might look something like this

```
-- files table    
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
blob MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL
mime_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
checksum VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
created_at DATETIME NOT NULL
```

You might have other columns that associate the file to a user or any other relevant information

Here are the size limits for the MySQL `TEXT` column types

```
TYPE          SIZE LIMIT
----------------------------------------------------
TINYTEXT      (2^8)   256 bytes
TEXT          (2^16)  65,536 bytes         (64 KiB)
MEDIUMTEXT    (2^24)  16,777,216 bytes     (16 MiB)
LONGTEXT      (2^32)  4,294,967,296 bytes  (4 GiB)
```

When you write to the DB using PHP, use the [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) function to encode the file.

If you cannot create `TEXT` column types, then you can forget saving the actual data in your database. You will then have to save the files to the filesystem and just store a link to the file in your database.

Or lastly, as another comment points out, you could use an external blob storage like Amazon S3 or other cloud pirate services.